# Google endpoint service use as proxy to call other api

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-endpoints

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to use cloud endpoint product to call other apis. So for example I found the configuration where you can call a cloud endpoint

```
    get:
      description: "Returns example"
      summary: "Example"
      operationId: example
      x-google-backend:
        address:
          http://another-host.com/example
```

My question is if I can in address specify header as well as that it is post request? Is it something possible or I need to create like a google function to actually call the right api?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do it in the [Cloud Endpoint OpenAPI extension](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/openapi-extensions#x-google-backend). You have to create a "proxy" manually, with cloud function for example.